# useState with useContext in Typescript

Tags: typescript, use-state, provider, use-context, createcontext

Lets say I have a basic setup for checking whether a user is logged in or not:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const UserContext = createContext<string | null>(null)
export default UserContext
```

In my App.tsx I want to create a useState hook so that I can manage the state of my context throughout my application:

```
//Context
const [context, setContext] = useState<string | null>(null)

  <UserContext.Provider value={{context, setContext}}>

    <Routes>

      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/> 
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/> 
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/> 
      <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin/>}></Route>

    </Routes>  

  </UserContext.Provider>
```

So as far as I can see I'll only ever need either the name of the logged in user, or set the state of the context to null if I want to deny access to certain pages. Now the issue is that typescript is yelling at me here, specifically in the value of the Provider:

```
Type '{ context: string | null; setContext: 
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I can force cast the value as follows:

```
value={{context, setContext} as any}
```

But that doesn't seem like a particularly elegant 'typescripty' solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you write `const UserContext = createContext<string | null>(null)` you are saying the value of your context is string or null but when you pass the value prop to the context provider you are passing an *object* with a *context property* that's string or null as well as a setter. You need to make the types match. Either just pass the context value from `useState` to the provider or change the type of your call to `useContext` to be an object with a string or null context property and a setter function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've typed your context as:

```
string | null
```

But then you provide a value for that context of (approxiamately) type:

```
{ context: string | null, setContext: (newString) => void }
```

So if you want the state setter in your context, then it needs to be part of the context's type:

```
const UserContext = createContext<{
  context: string | null,
  setContext: (newValue) => void
}>({
  context: null,
  setContext: () => undefined
})
```

Comment: Thanks. The code you provided still gave me some more errors but I altered it a bit, and I posted it below.

Answer (score 15):

Based on Alex's answer I came up with a tweak that works for me:

```
type UserContextType = {
     context: string | null,
     setContext: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>
 }

const iUserContextState = {
    context: null,
    setContext: () => {}
}

const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>(iUserContextState)

export default UserContext
```

And then in App.tsx:

```
//Context
const [context, setContext] = useState<string | null>(null)

  <UserContext.Provider value={{context, setContext}}>

    <Routes>

      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/> 
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/> 
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/> 
      <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin/>}></Route>

    </Routes>  

  </UserContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `useState`'s array as a return value, this is a correctly TypeScript solution:

```js
import React, { FC, createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

// Change shape of this object to your/app needs
const initialAppState = {
  userName: "",
};

export type AppState = typeof initialAppState;

type ContextType = [AppState, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<AppState>>];
const AppStateContext = createContext<ContextType>([] as unknown as ContextType);

type Props = {
  appState?: AppState;
};

/**
 * Provider to pass state to the React application
 */
export const AppStateProvider: FC<React.PropsWithChildren<Props>> = (props) => {
  const { appState = null } = props;
  const useStateRetValue = useState<AppState>(appState == null ? initialAppState : appState);

  return <AppStateContext.Provider value={useStateRetValue}>{props.children}</AppStateContext.Provider>;
};
AppStateProvider.defaultProps = {
  appState: undefined,
};

/**
 * Hook to access application state
 */
export const useAppStateContext = (): ContextType => useContext<ContextType>(AppStateContext);
```

Provider usage:

```
  <AppStateProvider>

    <Routes>

      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/> 
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/> 
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/> 
      <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin/>}></Route>

    </Routes>  

  </AppStateProvider>
```

Hook usage:

```
const [appState, setAppState] = useAppStateContext();

console.log(appState.userName);

useEffect(() => {
  setAppState({ userName: "John Doe" });
}, [setAppState]);

// ...or...

const [, setAppState] = useAppStateContext();

// ...or...

const [appState] = useAppStateContext();
```